# Onsubmit delay automatic url redirect

Tags: javascript, html

How to delay my page for 5 secs after clicking the submit button.

HTML:

```
    <form action="http://test123/wordpress/form/" method="post"  name="MyForm" onsubmit="return check()">
    // content
    //
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function check()
    {
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com",5000)
    }
    {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?");
    }


    function submitform()
    {

        document.UpdateMyForm.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Why? When you click on the submit button you expect immediate action. With the pause that you are inserting - how are you handling the timer if the user clicks multiple time because they think the form isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use redirect url in setimeout function.

```
function OnSubmitSuccess(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
       }, 5000)
 }
```